# I set up Google Analytics to show full url and now my pageview data has been separated

Tags: google-analytics, google-data

I followed these instructions https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012243?hl=en to show full URL in Google Analytics, because we have multiple third party sites included in our purchase flow...But a big issue I'm noticing now is that pageview data displays separately now.

Eg same month, Year-over-year view:
www.domainname.com/subpage
Aug 1-31 2017 Sessions - 5,000
Aug 1-31 2016 Sessions - 0

/subpage
Aug 1-31 2017 Sessions - 0
Aug 1-31 2016 Sessions 4,000

Is there some way to combine all this pageview data so that the subpages without the domains in front are combined with the full URL?

It's causing any data analysis to be very difficult.

I tried segments, but segments work by "sessions" and pull in other URL's that are part of the session but not specifically the URL I want to examine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the second Dimension "Hostname". Combined with the Path you will see the same as with your changes (www.domainname.com + /subpage). If you export the Data you can concat it again and analyze it.

In GA you have no possibility to merge the historical data of this two dimensions.